# Puzzle: "[] is symmetric"?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, integer, puzzle

I am trying to solve this enigma:

```
int direction = 1;
char direction_name = direction["nsew"];
```

Like why does it compile on a first place, what exactly is it trying to prove and what is it used for ?

---

*I spotted this code in a site with no relevant explanation other than "[] is symmetric". I mean what am I supposed to do with this information..*

Comment: for any array or pointer `p`, `i[p]` and `p[i]` come to share the same meaning, i.e. `*(p + i)`. the first form is perfectly valid and you can find it in standard. but indeed it's too bazaar so you can see it rarely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char direction_name = 1["nsew"];
    printf("[%c]\n",direction_name);
    return 0;
}
```

which [will print](https://ideone.com/tvzHZA) [s], because

```
char direction_name = 1["nsew"]; // "nsew" is string literal, i.e. an array
                                 // of 5 chars 'n' 's' 'e' 'w' '\0'
```

is equal to

```
char direction_name = "nsew"[1];
```

and also to

```
char direction_name = *("nsew" +1);
```

Therefore `[]` is symmetric in a sense that

```
x[y] == y[x] // if conditions given in C standard 6.5.2.1/2 are met
```

You can think of [] as an symmetric relation in algebra (under assumptions from 6.5.2.1 **§** 2):

[image]

Or you may think about [] as a linear mapping (transformation, functional) between [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space) ([Banach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space)) linear spaces V and V** if you wish:

```
x[f] = [f,x] = f[x]
```

---

C standard n1124 6.5.2.1 **§**  2 **Array subscripting** (emphasis main)

A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary + operator, if `E1` is an **array object** (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an **integer**, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th element of `E1` (counting from zero).

Comment: Ahh.. that looks weird. And the naming was pretty confusing to me.

Answer (score 3):

The following statement:

```
char direction_name = direction["nsew"];
```

is equivalent to:

```
char direction_name = "nsew"[direction];
```

as well as to:

```
char direction_name = *("nsew" + direction); // note that addition is commutative
```

The `direction` holds integer value `1`, hence you are getting second letter (in C arrays are indexed from zero) of *string literal* `"nsew"` (it is of array type `char[5]`), that is `'s'` character.

Comment: Can you also explain in what sense they are "symmetric". An orange and a banana cannot be the same thing without an appropriate explanation. Like.. `printf("%i", "asdf"[1] == 1["asdf"]);` means symmetric

Comment: @Malina: They are symmetric, because additiion is commutative. The expression `a[b]` is the same as `*(a + b)` using pointer notation, which is equivalent to `*(b + a)`, which implies `b[a]`.